# IMCE image upload option in ckeditor is not working in selected theme

Tags: drupal-7, ckeditor, imce-file-browser

Hi I have problem in image upload option with Imce module in Ckeditor.

When click on "Browse server" then a popup is opening in which there should be option to upload , delete etc and that is not coming.
This issue is getting solved when i am changing my theme to bartik or any other. But again once theme reverts the issue is coming back. 
Version which i am using are :

"Theme - Realia" , 
"Imce version - 7.x-1.9" , 
"Ckeditor version - 7.x-1.16" , 
"Drupal version  - 7.22 ".

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

This post (http://www.christianengvall.se/adding-imce-to-ckeditor-and-drupal-7/) Perfectly solves your problem.

In Addition to that.

- Pls check permission of `sites/default/files` folder .
- User permission to Upload Files
- Pls check Input Format.

Comment: Hi Jai. Thanks for your response. Actually when i am changing my theme then buttons are coming back.
In order to investigate, i found that there is js file of Realia theme is creating conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Finally as discussed got the issue in theme js file i.e. realia.js. 
And after that some css correction we have completed and got issue fixed.